# Making the hamming distance between two strings in a list at most 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a randomly generated list of values attached to a list (z) so what I did is convert two indexes next to each other to separate strings to compare each other. I need to make it so that the hamming distance is at most 3 between all strings in the list. I also can't use any modules for this.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
 z = ["AAATCG", "GAGCGT"]
 i = 0
 s1 = ""
 s2 = "" 
 while i < len(z) -1:
   s1 = z[i] 
   i = i+1
   s2 = z[i]
```

after that I'm lost

Comment: Could you include the code you are working with?

Comment: Edit your question & put it in there not in the comments

Comment: @DrBwts sorry just did it

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using a `for` loop. In the code below `z[0] = "AAATCG"` and `z[1] = "GAGCGT"`. The `if` statement checks if the letters in the strings are different, if they are than `ham_dist` is incremented by `1`.

```
# For the Hamming distance
ham_dist = 0
z        = ["AAATCG", "GAGCGT"]

for idx in range(len(z[0])):
    if z[0][idx] != z[1][idx]:
        ham_dist += 1
        
print(ham_dist)
```

If you want to edit the strings to reduce the Hamming distance to zero then the following code will edit the first string to replicate the second. If you want it the other way around just reverse the indicies.

```
z             = ["AAATCG", "GAGCGT"]
z_0_list      = list(z[0])
z_1_list      = list(z[1])
orig_ham_dist = 0
new_ham_dist  = 0
z_ouput       = []

# Calculate original Hamming distance & edit strings
for idx in range(len(z[0])):
    if z_0_list[idx] != z_1_list[idx]:
        z_0_list[idx] = z_1_list[idx]
        orig_ham_dist += 1
 
z_ouput.append("".join(z_0_list))
z_ouput.append("".join(z_1_list)) 
 
# Calculate new Hamming distance     
for idx in range(len(z_ouput[0])):
    if z_ouput[0][idx] != z_ouput[1][idx]:
        new_ham_dist += 1
        
print(orig_ham_dist)
print(z)
print('-------------------------')
print(new_ham_dist)
print(z_ouput)
```

Comment: wouldn't this just print the hamming distance and not edit the strings?

Comment: I have edited my reply. The above code will reduce the Hamming distance to `0` between the `2` strings